# Matrix representation for reciprocal functions?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, soft-question, representation-theory

I am well aware of the famous rotational matrices provide a representation to "counting up" the functions $\sin$ and $\cos$:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rr}\cos(\phi)&\sin(\phi)\\-\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)\end{array}\right]^k = \left[\begin{array}{rr}\cos(k\phi)&\sin(k\phi)\\-\sin(k\phi)&\cos(k\phi)\end{array}\right]$$

Some of my first questions on this site asked how to do similar things to hyperbolic functions and then later polynomials. Which I managed to build after a while.

But what about multiplicative reciprocal functions? Can we stuff functions of $t$ into a matrix $M$ somehow so that at least one element of $M^k$ will be $1/(kt)$ or $1/(kt)^2$

---

**Edit** I realized my matrix construction was a bit too restrictive.

What about : $${\bf M}^k{\bf Cv}$$

Instead of ${\bf M}^k$

Comment: No, powers of matrices never grow like that; you basically only get polynomials and exponentials (including complex exponentials, which is where sine and cosine come from).

Comment: Hmm you may be right. I have not gotten any answer, so I will just allow myself to change the question slightly, ok?

Comment: Your change makes no difference, you still only get polynomials and exponentials. ($C$ makes no difference at all, it's the same as using the vector $w = Cv$ instead of $v$ and setting $C = I$, and $v$ makes no difference because you can extend it to a basis, so up to change of basis you're still just asking about components of powers of matrices.) Writing down a proof is a bit tedious but you can do it using Jordan normal form.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : What about Carleman matrices. $C$ representing $x \to (1+x)^{-1}$, $M$ representing $x\to x-\Delta_x$, $v$ being the polynomial vector at $x=0$?

Comment: Generally speaking matrices have finitely many rows and columns; if you wanted to consider infinite matrices it would have been good to state that explicitly. With infinite matrices there are more possibilities.

Comment: Yep you are probably right. I looked at the truncated Carleman matrix for the reciprocal and the coefficients seem to grow combinatorically so we will get either numerical instability or no truncation will be sufficient to approximate the function everywhere we want to because of truncation errors.

Comment: But I really feel it should be possible to do *somehow*.

Comment: Only found 6 ways to do it so far. Anyone having more ideas is heartily welcome to share.